# How do I handle nil in models properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a chain of methods and at any time one of them could return nil based on what they're returning (a collection) and then a method on that collection will blow up because it is nil.

I'm not sure how to properly handle these cases? Should I do a if statement in each and explicitly return the method to stop the execution or what do I do?

```
undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass
# ./app/models/exercise.rb:132:in `last_placeholder_log_date'
# ./app/models/exercise.rb:136:in `placeholder_log_entries'
# ./app/models/exercise.rb:140:in `placeholder_log_entries!'

def last_placeholder_log_date(user)
  self.last_log_entry(user, true).created_at.beginning_of_day
end
```

How do I gracefully handle the possibility if there is no last log entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
def last_placeholder_log_date(user)
  self.last_log_entry(user, true).try(:created_at).try(:beginning_of_day)
end
```

With `try`, it's ensured that an exception is not raised if receiver does not respond.  If the receiver does not respond then the call returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Write code as :

```
def last_placeholder_log_date(user)
  val = last_log_entry(user, true)
  val.created_at.beginning_of_day unless val.nil?
end
```